# Database normalization multiple repetitions

Tags: database, database-normalization

I am programming an application and I need to do a database to store the data. The information is similar to the next simple example:

There are multiple restaurants and each restaurant has to send their food to the clients.

The database should be something like:

Restaurant | Food | Where to carry | Who carries

There are multiple restaurants (A, B, C, D...), the food is the same in all the restaurants (hamburgers, fish and salads), the people who carries the food could be working in all the restaurants, and the same house could be asking for food to diferent restaurants. All the information should be stored in a database.

In this case, I want to do a database at least in third normal form. Is it a good practice to make a single database and store all the data in this specific case?

I informed a lot but don't know if I'm doing it the right way because in this case the same information is repeated multiple times like Restaurant X food Y.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have tried to make a database with Restaurant | Food | Where to carry | Who carries but I donk know if it is the best solution because I have to repeat a lot of information

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to design it like this:

1. Restaurant table with the restaurant details i.e. id, name, address etc.
2. Food table with the food details i.e food name, food id, food price etc
3. Another table, which may be named as Orders, where you have the restaurant id, order id, house address from which the order was placed.
4. OrderFood table which contains the order id and food id where both are foreign keys and both combine to form the primary key.

And it is not a good practice to store everything in one table which increases redundancy. Hope this helps.